# Are IPv4 type of service and IPv6 traffic class equivalent to each other or is traffic class IPv6 specific?

Tags: ipv4, networking, ipv6, layer3, qos

IPv6 has a traffic class field. According to the specification it is an IPv6 length, out of which first 6 bits are called *code point or differential services code point* (**DSCP**) and the last 2 bits are used for *explicit congestion notification*(**ECN**). These 6 bit combinations (**DSCP**) are used to classify IP packets so that one class of IP packet can receive precedence over the other in a network.

IPv4 has a field, called type of service (ToS). According to some references it is also used to carry **DSCP** and **ECN** bits (as for example explained in a [video](https://youtu.be/3Y70y6dM7Cs)). However according to my professor IPv4 packets have no priority, which implies that this field is used for something else.

What is correct?

Comment: There is such a thing as overdoing formatting. Your question doesn't get more readable by using different types of fonts, bold and italic text all mixed up. Please consider applying formatting only where it has a real use.

Comment: It is DSCP (Differentiated Services Code Point), not DSCN.

Comment: and please provide references to the sources of your information

Comment: @effenok see this [video](https://youtu.be/3Y70y6dM7Cs)

Comment: who said that IPv4 packets have no priority?

Comment: @My professor has said.. And also I have many website..

Comment: you probably need to provide more context than this. this statement alone "IPv4 has no priority" is false. There might be a clue in context. The part about ToS field in the video applies equally to IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @effenok No this video is Ipv4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129606/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-effenok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why Ipv4 packets have no priority but Ipv6 packets have priority.

Both IPv4 and IPv6 packets use DSCP the same way. Neither IP actually uses the DSCP or ECN. Network devices can be configured to use those in various ways when there is congestion on an interface, but that is up to the network administrators. By default, network devices ignore DSCP and ECN. Neither field is used on the public Internet for either IP.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130006/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-are-ipv4-type-of-service-and-ipv6-traffic-cla).